# randomly select rows in linux without repeating it

Tags: linux

Please, I need help, as I am new to linux.
I have a file containing thousands of rows with duplicates. I want to randomly select rows in this file (based on the first column) without repeating any row. For example, I have a file like this;

```
233  7
233  8
244  9
244  8
244  7
255  5
288  6
300  4 
300  5
```

I want the output to be;

```
233  7
244  8
255  5
288  6
300  4
```

I already used `shuf -n N file > newfile`, but it repeats rows.
Please help with what code to use.

Comment: The "random" and "unique" are contradictory: if they are unique, they are not random anymore. However, you could use `uniq` or `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Hi!! One idea for you; You can use python to read and process your file. Write an script that open your file and read all rows in a set removing the second number (to do that use split). Then you have a array without repeated numbers. Then use rand() to take one. After that you can run your script using python myscript.py

Answer (score 1):

> what i would want is that the selection is not limited to the row that comes first. i want it in such a way that it could pick the first in some instance and also the second in another instance.

I'll rephrase your requirement as I understand it: You have a 2-column input file as shown in your question, sorted on the first column with duplicate values. You want an output that for each unique value of first column contains a random line with that value from the input.

This `awk` command produces this by simply giving the input lines **grouped by the 1st column value** to **distinct** instances of `shuf -n1`:

```
awk '$1 != c { close("shuf -n1"); c = $1 } { print|"shuf -n1" }' file
```

Comment: thanks Armali. this works perfectly. i would not have thought of this code on my own. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
sort -n -u test.txt | shuf -n 1
```

Comment: thanks @Simonare. that was helpful. however, what i would want is that the selection is not limited to the row that comes first. i want it in such a way that it could pick the first in some instance and also the second in another instance. my second column is based on age, and if only the first row is selected, then i am left with a file containing only the younger animals which i want to avoid.